# Is it possible to have a property_A depend on the value of a property_B belonging to a different json schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Let Schema_A be a given schema with a property P_a such that P_a is a number between 0.1 and 10.0 in increments of 0.1. I would like to know if it is possible to select a subset of properties Z s.t. Z is a subset of the properties of Schema_B using P_a as a selector.

For example, if Schema_B's properties are Pb1, Pb2, Pb3 I would like constrain Schema_B to contain only Pb1 and Pb2 iff P_a < 3.0, alternatively Schema_B should contain only Pb1 if 3.0 < P_a < 3.5, otherwise Schema_B should contain all properties (namely Pb1, Pb2 and Pb3)

**Schema_A:**

```
 {
    "$schema": "http://localhost/draft-04/schema#",
    "id": "http://localhost/schemas/schemaA.json",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Schema_A",
    "properties": {
        "P_a": {"type":"number",
                   "multipleOf": 0.1,
                   "exclusiveMinimum":0,
                   "maximum": 10
                   }
    },
    "required": ["key_A1"] 
}
```

**Schema_B**

```
{
        "$schema": "http://localhost/draft-04/schema#",
        "id": "http://localhost/schemas/schemaB.json",
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Schema_B",
        "properties": {
            "Pb1": {"type":"string", "enum":["X1", "Y1", "Z1"},
            "Pb2": {"type":"string", "enum":["X2", "Y2", "Z2"},
            "Pb3": {"type":"string", "enum":["X3", "Y3", "Z3"}
        }
    }
```

For example, let P_a = 2.0, then the below would be a a valid json instance of Schema_B:

```
{"Pb1":"X1", "Pb2":"Y2"}
```

An the below would be an **invalid** instances:

```
{"Pb1":"X1"}

{"Pb1":"X1", "Pb2":"Y2", "Pb3":"Y3"}
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: You need to clarify what exactly you want. In your explanation you seem to be talking about data instances and yet call them schemas. Also adding examples of what should be valid and invalid data would be helpful. Also it seems like the question can be simplified.

Comment: what does s.t. mean?

Comment: s.t. -> such that